# How do I use pre-load user information for logged-in user iOS/iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, entity-relationship

I am very new in iPhone App development. In my app, my users either have to log-in, or they would have been auto-logged via keychains services.

I am currently trying to allow my users to add friends. And in my entity, Player, I have added an inverse relationship to itself, named friend.

To create this function and link it as an IBAction to my Add button, I'm thinking of this:

```
-(void)addFriendFunction: (NSManagedObject *)user (UITextField *)newfriendName {

//fetches friend using friendName
NSManagedObject *newfriend = [self findFriendUsingFriendName:newfriendName];

//Add the friend to the user (owner of the phone)

NSSet *userFriends = [user friends]
[userFriends addObject:newfriend];

}
```

I'm not extremely sure that this code is correct, please guide me on this as well. My main question is, how do I get extract the user (logged-in user), so that I can pass it into this  function. Do I have to initialize a singleton during log-in? Or is there a better way that I could do it? For example, whether I can simply extract it using keychains or any pre-made tools that I'm unaware of.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems ok, rest for pre-populating the data you can look forward to the following links

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html

Apple developer tutorial really very well explained

Uses key chains and can help you with your problem. :)

Comment if you need help with anything else!

Possible duplicate of the post Can I access the keychain on the iPhone?

you can also download a demo project from here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007797

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not using `NSUserDefaults`?

Store `userId` during login;

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:userId forKey:@"userId"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

When app will launch check that the the `userId` is exist or not in `NSUserDefaults`

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"userId"]>0)
{
    //Load other resources against userId. and do what ever you want with your logged in user.
}
```